# Netbeans JApplet Webstart - icons not appearing on button when run

Tags: java, icons, netbeans-6.9, jbutton

Hey there - just wondering if anyone knows the trick to getting icons to display on button in a JApplet. When I add the icon from a png in my package via the properties panel it turns up in the NetBeans IDE as expected but when I run the launch file it isn't there. I can confirm that the file exists in my Jar and no exceptions seem to be thrown in relation to missing files.

If I create a similar application using a JForm and run it directly from NetBeans the icon appears as expected.

EDIT:

It seems this is confined to Chrome... works correctly in IE9 and FF 3.6

EDIT:

Replicate as follows - no coding required:

Create a NetBeans 6.9.1 Project with the following settings:

Java --> JavaApplication

[Next>]

Name e.g. JavaApplication1

Untick "Create Main Class"

[Finish]

Add a png image "MyIcon" to the src directory.

Right Click "JavaApplication1" Project in Projects panel and select New -> JApplet Form

[Finish]

Drag a button onto the form, right click -> properties -> icon and choose "MyIcon" from the pre-populated dropdown menu. You should see the icon appear on the button in the IDE.

Build the project, then navigate via explorer to the dist/launch.html file and run it in Firefox or IE and the icon will be there, run it an Chrome 10 and it won't.

Comment: Foe better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of failing code.  It does sound vaguely like yet another browser/JRE/applet interaction bug, but more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem magically went away and now I wish I had noted the exact version of Chrome that I had so that I could tell whether it updated or not. I worked around the problem but inadvertently left an icon on a button - I started work again today on my project and how-you-doing there was a lonely icon on a button - there are three possible reasons why this happened:

1 - I shut down my machine overnight; aka restart (93% Sure this was it)

2 - I moved the entire Netbeans project to another directory (5% Sure this was it)

3 - maybe but unlikely Chrome updated itself with a fix (2% Sure this was it)